# Where do I go for YouTube related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where do I go for YouTube-related questions? More specifically, I want to ask about the YouTube algorithm.

As an example: I wonder if uploading the video through the premiere will affect the algorithm

**My question is not related to development**: Someone said that if they just said YouTube algorithm, they were confused with development related parts, so I had to fix it.

I searched this site and others, but I couldn't find a suitable place to ask about the Youtube algorithm.

Comment: Surely only YouTube knows what algorithms it uses. You'd need to ask them unless they've published something in which case you still need to ask them where it is.

Comment: Algorithm or API? It's very different.

Comment: The properties of the YouTube algorithm are not entirely unknown. Think [shocked faces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln1qbgZz_TQ&t=14m20s) or the 10 minutes length rule (may not be that important any more).

Comment: Could you please provide a *specific example question**? Knowing what angle you're taking with the question will be helpful for answers

Comment: Your edit adds nothing, saying "my question is *not* about something" does not help, we need to know what it is about, not what it is not about. I didn't vote to delete, but not voting to reopen it as well.

Comment: If your goal is to get the question reopened, you need to edit in a fully-detailed example question that you intend to ask. The nuances of it will influence the recommendations people give.

Answer (score 9):

If your question relates to **using** YouTube (or its algorithm) as a creator or consumer, you could try [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Please review [their policies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Stack Overflow is the best place for it. [This help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentions how questions asking after "a software algorithm" are on topic.

Searching for "youtube algorithm" gives [quite an extensive list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube+algorithm) already.

Comment: "*The* YouTube Algorithm" typically refers to the proprietary algorithm that YouTube uses to promote videos. It's not just any algorithm involving YouTube. Questions about *the* YouTube algorithm would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I want to ask questions that not related to development!

Comment: @Minecraft so your question is unclear and you just waste people's time. Please explain, as you've [**already been asked**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381685/where-do-i-go-for-youtube-related-questions#comment1273165_381685), what kind of questions you mean.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what's unclear. 

As VLAZ said,

I've stated that I've browsed all sites and never said YouTube API. And the YouTube Algorithm usually means just the YouTube system itself, not the API. (Especially because this site is not a development related site)

Comment: @VLAZ That could be the case ("typically", indeed, which still isn't a counterargument to my answer here), but it could also have been a misused article, or simply *the* algorithm the OP wants to ask about. Like I state in my answer, SO is for software algorithms (certainly within reasonable parameters, but that's not something I need to warn against given this broad question). I really think you're reaching, without further details. The OP asked a general question, I gave a general answer.

Comment: "*("typically", indeed, which still isn't a counterargument to my answer here)*" I did not realise, I was supposed to give a counter-argument. I thought it was self-evident. Let me be perfectly clear, in that case *the* YouTube algorithm is not something you can or should ask on Stack Overflow. It is a ranking system. It is akin to SEO - there is an algorithm *involved* but [it's not within the purview of SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341003/blacklist-the-seo-tag). Ranking algorithms are not about tailoring your content, not software development.

Comment: "*I really think you're reaching, without further details.*" no, I wasn't. And as has become evident you didn't have enough details to even answer the question - whether it is a software question or content promotion question. Yet in the light of this information, you claim it's *me* who is reaching? Moreover, seems like OP has confirmed this. I'd take that as a counterargument to your claim that I was reaching. Since apparently this is some sort of debate or whatever.

Comment: @Minecraft with bit of clarifying your question can be useful, as it stands it's not because it's unclear. If what VLAZ said it correct then add it to the question to explain, you can't expect visitors to read comments on answers to figure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: @VLAZ in that case, I apologize. I had interpreted the question as a general inquiry into what platform might be suitable, similar to others I've seen here. Yes, it lacked detail, but so do others of this sort at times. I also definitely got your reasoning, but saw the idea that the OP asked for that particular algorithm as your assumption, just like how I assumed--as I mentioned--that it was intended more generally. In any case, sorry if my tone was rude.